# http headers in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What is HTTP headers in asp.net. How do they work? I want to use them to cache in output cache for varybyheader.

Comment: If you don't know what HTTP Headers are for, why do you want to use them for output caching? Perhaps understanding this will help us answer your question =)

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CachingInASPNETVaryByParamMayNeedVaryByHeader.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output caching in asp.net can be done by means of declarative syntax meaning in the markup page you can declare them alone with page directives .Syntax given below.

<%@ OutputCache Duration="#ofseconds"
   Location="Any | Client | Downstream | Server | None | 
     ServerAndClient "
   Shared="True | False"
   VaryByControl="controlname"
   VaryByCustom="browser | customstring"
   VaryByHeader="headers"
   VaryByParam="parametername" 
   VaryByContentEncoding="encodings"
   CacheProfile="cache profile name | ''"
   NoStore="true | false"
   SqlDependency="database/table name pair | CommandNotification"
   ProviderName="Provider Name"
%>

Suppose if you want to cache the page based on the language you can use the HTTP headers called "Accept Language". So if it will cache page content for languages specific like French,Chinese,Japanese.

**<%@ OutputCache Duration="10800" VaryByParam="State;City" 
  VaryByHeader="Accept-Language" %>**

Like this you can cache the page based on HTTP headers .

Accept Content-Types that are acceptable Accept: text/plain 
Accept-Charset Character sets that are acceptable Accept-Charset: utf-8 
Accept-Encoding Acceptable encodings Accept-Encoding:  
Accept-Language Acceptable languages for response Accept-Language: en-US

Links referred:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972362.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Answer (score 4):

Each piece of data is transmitted over the internet via a protocol called HTTP - you can't do anything about this as its the way the internet has been designed.

Each piece of this data is seperated up into chunks - each of which needs a *header* to provide an explanation to its contents, this is a **HTTP Header**.

Using these headers you can request the browser to perform certain actions on your behalf (it is under no obligation to follow) such as:

- Redirect to another page
- **Request the browser to cache**

I believe the second is the one you require.

ASP.NET is wonderful however - you don't need to fiddle about with HTTP Headers.  [**The framework will do that for you**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z852zf6b.aspx).

Comment: Really nice answer to an evasive question !

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article that might help you with this: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506093425/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120209-1.aspx). To quote: "HTTP Headers are used to provide the web server with information to assist with handling the request"

Hope it helps.

Comment: ... and the browser. You have both Request and Response http headers :)